# nodejs variable inside express response.write

Tags: node.js, express

Assume I have a dynamic way to set the value of `toggle` to `true` or `false` without restarting the app.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Namely print different results based on the value of `toggle`?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

var toggle = true;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Demo Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>`);

  if (toggle) {
    res.write(`<p>Hello World. Toggle Value: true</p>`);
  }
  else {
    res.write(`<p>Hello World. Toggle Value: false</p>`);
  }

  res.write(`</body></html>`);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: you  can write one API to update value..!

Comment: What? I know how to change the value of toggle. I'm asking if this is the most efficient way to print different HTML based *on* the value of `toggle`.

Comment: Do you intend to print out more than just the value of `toggle` depending upon whether toggle is true or false? For instance, `if (!toggle)` then `res.write("<p>Hello Mars</p>");`? Or are you simply printing the value of the `toggle` variable? If you are keying off toggle to display different text, then yes, this is the simplest way. If you're just printing the value of the toggle variable, you don't need an if then, and can use `${toggle}` in the template string, as you do with `${port}` in the app.listen.

Comment: Didn't understand you want to print the value or store toggle in proper way..?
You can store value in the database/file and on restart of the app get data from db to a variable. On update of toggle again update in db and variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat strings to write single line return

```
res.write(`<p>Hello World. Toggle Value: ` + true + `</p>`);
```

Or using ES6 features

```
res.write(`<p>Hello World. Toggle Value: ${true}</p>`);
```

I would recommend you using some view engine such as mustache or pug, where you would pass 'toggle' variable and handle rendering inside template.